# Entity framework core adding a record and getting "Delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint.."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with .net core 2.1 and am encountering a strange intermittent issue.

In my case I have these three tables with entities (simplified):

```
Table("Establishment")]
public class Establishment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

Table("ServiceUser")]
public class ServiceUser
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
    prop int ChangedBy {get; ;set} //The id of the current user account
}

Table("EstablishmentServiceUser")]
public class EstablishmentServiceUser
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int EstablishmentId {get; set;}
    public int ServiceUserId{get; set;}

    public Establishment Establishment {get;set;}
    public ServiceUser ServiceUser {get;set;}
}
```

In order to add a new EstablishmentServiceUser in code I am doing something like this:

```
var estabServiceUser = new EstablishmentServiceUser 
{
    establishmentId = 1
    serviceuser.Firstname = "John",
    serviceUser.Lastname = "Smith",
    serviceUsers.ChangedBy = 1 //This is a user that definitely exists
}
_sqlContext.EstablishmentServiceUsers.Add(estabServiceUser);
_sqlContext.SaveChanges();
```

So far this has worked fine and a new entry is created in the ServiceUser table with the firstname and lastname and a new entry is created in the establishmentServiceUser table with an entry linking the serviceUser to the establishment.

Suddenly I am encountering an error for one user (but not another) where the code hangs for a while and then gives the following exception:

```
SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 
"FK_ServiceUser_EstablishmentAccount". The conflict occurred in database 
"SafeSteps", table "dbo.ServiceUser", column 'ChangedBy'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I guess my main question is **why is entity framework trying to delete something in the process of doing an insert?**

Any insight, help or guidance would be very much appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:
I have fixed the issue for now by removing the foreign key constraint in the database. The question still remains as to how I could make it work with that constraint in there.

Comment: In order to give you an answer, you need to show the missing part of the entity model/configuration - to see where is `FK_ServiceUser_EstablishmentAccount` constraint coming from and how is the relationship configured in EF. To me it sounds like wrongly configured one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev that's a very useful comment actually because I don't have any other configuration other than the navigation properties on the entities. Perhaps this is something I am missing.

Comment: Seems like your `ChangedBy` property is linked to something called `EstablishmentAccount`, can u update your question with that entity and its configurations. Perhaps any fluent configurations as well that are being applied to your DbContext.